# Android get result from Camera Intent in onNewIntent

Tags: android, startactivityforresult, onnewintent

I have an Activity with `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` . I want launch camera from this and then process result, but `startActivityForResult` doesn't work with singleInstance. So maybe it's possible to get result from camera using `onNewIntent` method? If it's possible, how can I implement this?

Comment: that a typo for launchmode?

Comment: no, I need launchMode singleInstance for some features, but now I have no idea, how can I use camera intent with this

Comment: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`<-- compare with what you said.

Comment: Oh, that was mistake, thanks :)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at both singleTask and singleInstance.

**singleTask:**

The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.

> Note: Although the activity starts in a new task, the Back button
>   still returns the user to the previous activity.

**singleInstance:**

Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task; any activities started by this one open in a separate task.

> Note: That means, the activity with launch mode is always in a single
>   activity instance task. This is a very specialized mode and should
>   only be used in the applications that are implemented entirely as one
>   activity.

You could try something like this

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {

        try {
            //load image goes 

         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
         }
    }
}
```